# How to add the json response into spinner in android using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

In our project we don't hard code the Label and `dropdown`, we assign the value to Label from `JSON`. I don't understand how to assign the gender `array` to `dropdown`.
Here is the response getting from URL

```
{
    "statusCode": "200",
    "statusMessage": "SUCCESS",
    "meetmeConfig": {
        "id": "bb52dc0f-29d0-4079-99c7-a07c8045a829",
        "moduleName": "MeetMe",
        "createdDate": 1523962430721,
        "configContent": {
            "trackingOptions": [
                {
                    "optionName": "Before the meet",
                    "isTimeRequired": true,
                    "trackingTime": [
                        5,
                        10,
                        15
                    ],
                    "isDeleted": false
                },
                {
                    "optionName": "After the meet",
                    "isTimeRequired": true,
                    "trackingTime": [
                        5,
                        10,
                        15
                    ],
                    "isDeleted": false
                },
                {
                    "optionName": "At the start",
                    "isTimeRequired": false,
                    "trackingTime": [],
                    "isDeleted": false
                },
                {
                    "optionName": "Never",
                    "isTimeRequired": false,
                    "trackingTime": [],
                    "isDeleted": false
                }
            ],
            "numberOfParticipants": 8,
            "mapResetTimeInterval": 30,
            "meetingTrackableTime": 3600,
            "addressTypes": [
                "Home",
                "Work"
            ],
            "transportModes": [
                "Walking",
                "Driving"
            ],
            "gender": [
                "Male",
                "Female",
                "Trans-Female",
                "Bi-Gender",
                "Non-Binary",
                "Gender nonconfirming",
                "Undisclosed",
                "Rather not say"
            ],
            "toastDelayTimeForPulse": 3,
            "syncToastMaxTimeInterval": 300,
            "syncToastThirdTimeInterval": 180,
            "firstTimeInterval": 1,
            "secondTimeInterval": 2,
            "meetmeSearchContactTimeInterval": 2,
            "signupToastDelayTime": 4,
            "signupToastdelatimebysix": 6,
            "signupToastDelayMedium": 5,
            "profileToastDelayTime": 4,
            "profileToastDelatimebysix": 6,
            "languages": [
                "English",
                "Spanish",
                "Marathi",
                "Hindi",
                "Bengali",
                "French",
                "Arabic",
                "German",
                "Italian",
                "Dutch",
                "Japanese",
                "Russia",
                "Korean"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use gender array getting from response and added to a `Spinner` which is in a fragment.
Here is the code in `onResponse` method.

```
heroList =  response.body();   
data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(heroList));                                                

Log.d("Data","Datarecevied:"+heroList.getMeetmeConfig().getConfigContent().getGender());
```

How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
List anyList = heroList.getMeetmeConfig().getConfigContent().getGender()

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.msSpinnerID);

ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, anyList);

adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(adp);
```

**If you want show on Dialog**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(DialogActivity.this);
builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
builderSingle.setTitle("Select One Name:-");
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DialogActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
  List anyList = heroList.getMeetmeConfig().getConfigContent().getGender()
for(gender : anyList)
{
arrayAdapter.add(gender)
}
builderSingle.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
builderSingle.setAdapter(arrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String strName = arrayAdapter.getItem(which);
                Log.e("My Selected Gender", strName)
       }
        });
builderSingle.show();
```

Comment: I fetch the response  on onCreate() when application is started and my spinner situated in an fragment

Comment: this code will work on both side either activity or fragment.

Comment: I am getting Response When app started and I want to send the response data to an Fragment which is inside the Activity .I tried to send using bundle but I get the NullPointer exception in an fragment

Comment: are you hitting api on Activity or Fragment?

Comment: In an Base activity

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your JSON Response, there is an Android Library called Ason found here https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5313

You can use the libary to fetch the array that you would want to use on your spinner way easier. Its a wrapper of `org.json` in android.

So your array will be constructed as follows:

```
Ason ason = new Ason(urlResponse);
AsonArray genderArray = ason.getJsonArray('meetmeConfig.configContent.gender')

//then u convert the genderArray into an array or ArrayList thats spinners use
ArrayList<String> spinnerItems = new ArrayList();
for (Ason gender : genderArray){
    spinnerItems.add(gender.toString());
}
```

use the `spinnerItems` for the spinner adapter

Comment: Github says that's deprecated library, but it's basically JSONpath. Also Retrofit already parses the data using Gson

Comment: No, The Ason one

Answer (score 0):

```
 AppCompatSpinner spinner;
 spinner = (AppCompatSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
 ArrayList<String> categoryDropDownItems = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In Your Response

```
categoryDropDownItems.add("<Set Title if you want>");

 //Array Response from Server
 if (response != null) {
     if (response.length() > 0) {
         for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
             try {
                 JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                 String dropDownDisplayCategoryName = jsonObject.getString("<YOUR STRIN FROM JSON>");                  
                 categoryDropDownItems.add(dropDownDisplayCategoryName);
             } catch (JSONException je) {
                 return null;
             }
         }
      } else {
          return null;
      }
 }
```

//For Set Array Data in Spinner

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item, categoryDropDownItems);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setSelection(selection);
```

If you want to pass data from Activity to Fragment you can Use

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragmentName();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("RESPONSE",<Your Response as a String>);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

And Get Data in Fragment like below

```
String responseData = getArguments().getString("RESPONSE");
```

Now you can convert your object in `JSON` and from `JSON` get `Spinner` data and use above code for Add data in `ArrayList` and set to `Spinner`.

Comment: I am getting response in an activity and i want use the response on fragment how can I do that

Comment: You can pass string response From Activity to Fragment  using Bundle and get Data In Fragment. Wait I will post example in few min

Comment: I am get Null pointer exception Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList android.os.Bundle.getCharSequenceArrayList(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Is there another way to pass the retrofit response from one activity to another fragment that is situated in anothe folder but same package .

Comment: You have to debug and check for exception , I am using above code in many app at many places it is work file. And my app scenario is same as yours

Comment: You can also pass data using `BroadcastReceiver` but not recommended for this issue.

Comment: Is there any way to save  async response anywhere and we can use them from anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this code and your problem will be solved.Thank you

```
ArrayAdapter<String> genderAdapter;
Spinner spin_gender = findViewById(R.id.spin_gender);

heroList =  response.body();   
data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(heroList));                                                

String[] genderArray = heroList.getMeetmeConfig().getConfigContent().getGender()

genderAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.label, genderArray);
spin_gender.setAdapter(genderAdapter);
```